# Word / term suggestion about "love or any emotinal relation in office, workplace"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there any word / term about "love or any emotinal relation in office, workplace"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please review the guidance for making [tag:single-word-requests], as well as the site [tour] and [help], to see if you can [edit] your question to meet our standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term I've heard most often is ***office romance***.  Note that they're usually [a bad idea](https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/office-romance-danger-ahead).  There's an old saying: *don't go fishing off the company pier*.  It means don't look for love at work.

I will note that the Wikipedia article on the topic is called ***[workplace romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workplace_romance)***, but I think the former is far more common.  ([Google's ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=office%20romance%2C%20workplace%20romance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coffice%20romance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworkplace%20romance%3B%2Cc0) agrees.)